# Calling Pandas df.sort_values() multiple times on the same column gives different results?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example below... why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list(range(150)), 'b': [1, 2, 3] * 50})
>>> df.sort_values('b').equals(df.sort_values('b').sort_values('b'))
False
>>> df.sort_values('b').head()
       a  b
0      0  1
39    39  1
42    42  1
45    45  1
132  132  1
>>> df.sort_values('b').sort_values('b').head()
       a  b
0      0  1
87    87  1
120  120  1
84    84  1
81    81  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me working specify `mergesort` like only one stable sorting method in [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), because if sorting by only one column is default method `kind=quicksort`:

> **kind**{‘quicksort’, ‘mergesort’, ‘heapsort’}, default **quicksort**
>
> Choice of sorting algorithm. See also ndarray.np.sort for more information. mergesort is the only stable algorithm. For DataFrames, this option is only applied when sorting on a single column or label.

If sorting by multiple columns default is `mergesort`.

```
print (df.sort_values('b', kind='mergesort').head())
     a  b
0    0  1
3    3  1
6    6  1
9    9  1
12  12  1

print (df.sort_values('b', kind='mergesort').sort_values('b', kind='mergesort').head())
     a  b
0    0  1
3    3  1
6    6  1
9    9  1
12  12  1
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation! I wish they made the stable algorithm the default, seems to me like premature optimization with a hard to debug side-effect.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but it is too long.

According to docs for [DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

> kind: .. mergesort is the only stable algorithm.

You getting different results for column `a` because there is no guarantee that the order of ***equivalent*** elements in column `b` will be retained during sorting. And since the column `b` consists of `1`s only, order of the elements are undetermined. You can either use `mergesort` as suggested by **jezrael**, or sort by column `b` then by column `a`.

Also, please see [Quick Sort vs Merge Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort-vs-merge-sort/) for additional info. The most important point regarding your question is

> 7. Stability :
>      Merge sort is stable as two elements with equal value appear in the same order in sorted output as they were in the input unsorted array.
>      Quick sort is unstable in this scenario.