# In cycle sort algorithm, I was looking for a case where we observe the unstable nature of the algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I was reading about the cycle sort algorithm and found out that it is unstable in nature, however, I am having difficulty in coming up with a case that shows the unstable nature of the cyclic algorithm.
Could someone give a case where we can observe the unstable nature of the algorithm?

More information on the algorithm:-
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort

Here is my code for Cycle sort algorithm:-

```
        #include <iostream> 

        using namespace std;

        int main()
        {
            int n;
            cin >> n;
            int *arr;
            arr=new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                cin >> arr[i];
            int cyStart, item, pos;
            for (int cyStart = 0; cyStart < (n - 1); cyStart++)
            {
                item = arr[cyStart];
                pos = cyStart;
                for (int i = cyStart + 1; i < n; i++)
                {
                    if (item > arr[i])
                        pos++;
                }
                if (pos == cyStart)
                    continue;
                while (item == arr[pos])
                    pos++;
                if (item != arr[pos])
                    swap(arr[pos], item);
                while (cyStart != pos)
                {
                    pos = cyStart;
                    for (int i = cyStart + 1; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        if (item > arr[i])
                            pos++;
                    }
                    while (item == arr[pos])
                        pos++;   
                    if (item != arr[pos])
                        swap(arr[pos], item);
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                cout << arr[i] << " ";
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: What is the "cyclic algorithm"? Perhaps provide a description or a link, since I don't think it's well-known.

Comment: I also suggest you pick up [a decent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) or two, and learn more about the standard library and what it can help you with (for example by using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) rather than allocating memory explicitly).

Comment: Stability of sorting algorithm can only be observed when sorted elements have some characteristic that is not taken into account when sorting. For `int`, stable or unstable algorithm will produce exactly the same result. For `struct X {int n; std::string name;};`, if you sort such structures by `n` value only, you might notice a difference.

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61202074/calling-pandas-df-sort-values-multiple-times-on-the-same-column-gives-differen). I believe it is exactly the case you looking for, except that sorting is done using Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So let's say we have a group of data as below:[image]
2 sets of letter "A" to "E". To better differentiate them, I'm gonna call duplicate data with a number attached to them. So "A"s would be "A1" and "A2" and so on.
[image]
Now let's try to sort them based on the algorithm you mentioned.

- Step 1:
  [image]
  Taking the first data out, and find the place it should be put to. Since we know there are 10 items, or 2 sets of 5 identical items, we know "E1" would be placed to the 9th place.
- Step 2:
  [image]
  "E1" is put into 9th place, and the item that was in 9th place before is taken out to be sorted.
- Step 3:
  [image]
  "E2" is put into 10th place, "D2" is taken out to be sorted.
- Step 4:
  [image]
  "E2' is put into 7th place, "B2" is taken out to be sorted.

  ## **Now you might have noticed a problem!!**

  "D2" is put into 7th place, which means "D1" can only be put into 8th place, despite it should be put in front of "D2".

  Well, this is what an "unstable sort" means. The result of the sort would be independent from the order of the original data!

---

**Continue the sort:**

- Step 5: [image]
- Step 6: [image]
- Step 7: [image]
- **You have just completed the first cycle.**
- Starting the next cycle:
- Step 8: [image]
- Step 9: [image]
- Step 10: [image]
- Step 11: [image]
- Step 12: [image]
- **You have just completed your sort**

Now look at your data, you would notice that 2 pairs of data were sorted unstably:[image]